# How to disable a Spring Cloud Stream Kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Here is my situation:

We have a Spring cloud Stream 3 Kafka service connected to **multiple topics** in the same broker but I want to control connecting to a specific topic based on properties.

Every topic has its own binder and binding but the broker is the same for all.

I tried disabling the binding (that was the only solution I found so far) by using the property below  and that works for the StreamListener to not receive messages but the connection to the topic and rebalancing is still happening.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        ...
        anotherBinding:
          consumer:
            ...
            autostartup: false
```

I wonder if there is any setting on binder level that prevents it from starting. One of the topics consumer should only be available in one of the environments.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the bindings by setting `autoStartup` to `false` should work, I am not sure what the issue is.

It doesn't look like you are using the new functional model, but the `StreamListener`. If you are using the functional model, here is another thing that you can try. You can disable the bindings by not including the corresponding functions at runtime. For example, assume you have the following two consumers.

```
@Bean
public Consumer<String> one() {}

@Bean
public Consumer<String> two() {}
```

When running this app, you can provide the property `spring.cloud.function.definition` to include/exclude functions. For instance, when you run it with `spring.cloud.function.definition=one`, then the consumer `two` will not be activated at all. When running with `spring.cloud.function.definition=two`, then the consumer `one` will not be activated.

The downside to the above approach is that if you decide to start the other function once the app started (given `autoStartup` is `false` on the other function), it will not work as it was not part of the original bindings through `spring.cloud.function.definition`. However, based on your requirements, this is probably not an issue as you know which environments are targeted for the corresponding topics. In other words, if you know that consumer `one` needs to always consume from the topic `one`, then you don't include consumer `two` as part of the definition.

Comment: Hi sobychacko, thanks for the answer. For the new projects we already use the kafka consumers as functional programing but that other project is a legacy one and still use the old way.

Yes, using autoStartup: false in the legacy prevents the StreamListener from receiving the messages but we still the connection to the topic and rebalancing going on. For now we will leave this binder commented out in code while we don't migrate to functional programming consumer beans. Thanks!